# С миру по нитке - голому рубаха

Tags: фразеология

Что означает этот фразеологизм?

Answer (score 2):

С миру по нитке — голому рубашка (рубаха)
С МИРУ ПО НИТКЕ — ГОЛОМУ РУБАШКА (рубаха). Ото всех понемногу — и получается нечто значительное, ощутимое для кого-л. одного. Говорится тогда, когда сообща помогают в чём-л., что не по средствам или не по силам одному.— Странное дело,— говорил он [Слепцов],— на всякий пустяк люди бросают деньги, а чуть коснется чего-нибудь полезного, так не уломаешь их принять участие.. Ну, да обойдемся и без них: с миру по нитке — голому рубашка. Панаева, Воспоминания. Ведь теперь дело <всенародное?: война за свободу. У власти — «демократия». Нечего на буржуев надеяться, когда-то они тряхнут кошельками. Надо твердо помнить старую русскую пословицу: «С миру по нитке — голому рубашка». И потекут на фронт новые пушки, пулеметы, снаряды, патроны и революционные молодые солдаты. Все дыры на фронте <залатаем>! Дыбенко, Из недр царского флота к великому Октябрю. Не подражая степенному старьевщику, который держится поговорки, что «с мира по нитке — голому рубашка,— кулак живет, мало думая о завтра, живет «не в год, а в рот». Кокорев, Кулак и барышник.— Семьсот рублев деньги для волости невелики-то...— А мы завсегда рады уважить хорошему человеку...— С миру по нитке — голому рубаха! Эртель, Записки Степняка. А не знает, что тут грошика если не возьмешь,— разоришься, кругом разоришься; а для меня таперича он копейку, другой копейку... говорится пословица: <С миру по нитке...? Н. Успенский, Старуха.
  — Конечно, благодарение господу, без пользы не торгуем. Есть, ваше растаковство, такая пословица: с голого по нитке — сытому рубашка! — заключает негоциант. Салтыков-Щедрин, Письма о провинции. Раздался звонкий голос Перфишки, покрывая весь шум в трактире. Сапожник певучей скороговоркой кричал: — И-эх, лей, кубышка, хозяйского добришка! Будем пить, будем баб любить, будем по миру ходить! С миру по нитке — бедному петля! А от той петли избавишься — на своих жилах удавишься. М. Горький, Трое. Спасибо Коксострою, что он раскошелился.. Вот теперь — Коксострой, а там, глядишь, другое какое ведомство отпустит средства еще на что-нибудь, вот мы и... обрастем мясом... С миру по нитке и... как это говорится...— институту халат,— договорил за него Голубин-СКИЙ. Сергеев-Ценский, Искать, всегда искать!
—    Снегирев: С миру по нитке — голому рубаха; Даль: С миру по нитке — голому рубаха; Михельсон: С миру по нитке — бедному рубаха;   Рыбникова: С  миру  по нитке — голому  рубашка.
http://slovarick.ru/916/

Answer (score 1):

В принципе можно двояко рассматривать, с различным, хотя в чем-то и сходным, смыслом.
Исходно - как призыв к взаимопомощи (мир здесь люди, окружение), что совсем необременительно каждому. Либо как указание на то, что большое складывается из малого, в последнем смысле часто используется сейчас, исходный вытесняется.

Что до этимологии, то в расшифровке она не нуждается, значения слов не слишком отличаются от обычных, а смысл фразы вытекает из значений составляющих. Так что это даже не идиома, в отношении которой обычно задают подобные вопросы о смысле, Гораздо ближе просто к крылатому выражению.